# How do I replace a sprite in unity with another one?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay so I've been making a 2d platformer and had a terrible image/sprite for my player. Now I've got a better one and want to just replace the images but keep all the same values and data/scripts etc.

I've been trying to figure it out for awhile but to no avail. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to permanently change a sprite on your prefabs/objects you can drag the new sprite from your asset folder to into the "Sprite Renderer" Component of the object you want to change, replacing whatever is currently in the sprite box. Check out this image to see exactly where you want to drag the sprite:

[image]

O you can change it via script using a public variable:

```
public class ChangeSprite: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite newSprite;

    private void ChangeSprite(){
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite == newSprite;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, not sure it is the best way but it works, is to:
- import your new Sprite (let's call it SpriteB)
- select the GameObject where you have been using your first sprite (SpriteA)
- in the "Sprite Renderer" component of your selected GameObject, replace "Sprite=SpriteA" with your new sprite so that "Sprite=SpriteB"

Obviously you will have to repeat the operation for every GameObject where you may have used SpriteA.